# enumerate grid columns in order

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am using an [UltraGrid](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid_members.html) control from Infragistics. I am able to get a strongly typed enumeration of the [UltraGridColumns](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn_members.html) using the below code:

```
(this.grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns).Cast<UltraGridColumn>();
```

How can I order this enumeration such that it is the same as in the UI? (The user is able to rearrange columns freely).

Is there a property that I can use to order by or use to sort on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order is in the headers (yeah...):

```
this.grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns).Cast<UltraGridColumn>()
    .OrderBy(c => c.Header.VisiblePosition);
```